# NSData isEqualtoData

Tags: objective-c, nsdata

I really don't understand what's going on here.

I have a function that is getting the first 3 bytes from an NSData object, receivedStream, and putting them into another NSData object, temp, via a char array. Then comparing that to an NSData object created from a char array buffer. Both new NSData objects are created and have the correct contents. However, when isEqualtoData is called, I get an error:

> [NSConcreteData isEqualtoData:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance ***(instance refers to tmp2)***

I also get the warning

> Instance method '-isEqualtoData:' not found (return type defaults to 'id')

which I don't understand as it's clear that this is a valid method in the docs. Do I need to declare NSData.h somewhere?

```
-(BOOL)checkHeader{
    char tmp[3];
    [receivedStream getBytes:&tmp length:3];
    NSData *temp = [NSData dataWithBytes:tmp length:3];
    NSData *tmp2 = [NSData dataWithBytes:header length:3];
    BOOL test = [tmp2 isEqualtoData:temp];
    return test;
}
```

Comment: Just edit the post, man. I made a copy&paste of your code and took me 10 minutes to figure out what was wrong xD

Answer (score 32, accepted):

The method is called `isEqualToData:`. Note the capital T – Objective-C is case-sensitive, as most programming languages.

Comment: I knew it was going to be something stupid like that. Thanks. That'll teach me to copy the method straight from the docs.